# WooCommerce Adding Text after price for certain shipping method

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a problem adding a short text like "(incl. VAT)", after the shipping-price tag on the checkout page.

The main problem is that it has to be a certain shipping method in a certain Zone (zone_id=1) but I don't know how to access this certain shipping method.

Anyone knows how to solve this?
Greetings!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'custom_shipping_labels', 10, 2 );

function custom_shipping_labels(){
        if ( $method->cost > 0) {
            if ( WC()->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
                // $label = $method->get_label()." : ".wc_price( $method->cost); //default

                $method_ID = $method->get_ID(); //retrieve the ID of the method label

                // $label = $method->get_label()." : ".wc_price( $method->cost )." ->".$method_ID; // This shows you each method id next to the label


                //Some conditions here
                switch ($method_ID) {
                    case "flat_rate:1":
                        $label = $method->get_label()." : ".wc_price( $method->cost )."(incl. VAT)"; // This show text "(Incl. VAT)"
                        break;
                    case "flat_rate:4":
                        $label = $method->get_label()." : ".wc_price( $method->cost )."(incl. VAT)"; // This show text "(Incl. VAT)"
                        break;
                    // etc...
                    default:
                        $label = $method->get_label()." : ".wc_price( $method->cost); //default
                }

                if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
                    $label .= ' <small>' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
                }
            } else {

                // $label = wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() );// default


                $method_ID = $method->get_ID(); //retrieve the ID of the method label

                // $label = $method->get_label()." : ".wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() )." ->".$method_ID; // This shows you each method id next to the label


                //Some conditions here
                switch ($method_ID) {
                    case "flat_rate:1":
                        $label = $method->get_label()." : ".wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() )."(incl. VAT)"; // This show text "(Incl. VAT)"
                        break;
                    case "flat_rate:4":
                        $label = $method->get_label()." : ".wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() )."(incl. VAT)"; // This show text "(Incl. VAT)"
                        break;
                    // etc...
                    default:
                        $label = $method->get_label()." : ".wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() ); //default
                }




                if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && ! WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
                    $label = ' <small>' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To be used in functions.php in theme directory.

Use the switch to make some conditions according to the method ID (Remove the commented line to echo each method ID)